# When in draw mode, creating lines/curves, how do I drop or finish the line?

Tags: draw-mode

I can't find the right button or instructions on how to place this line into the frame. When using the pen tool, the object drawn automatically places once I release the LMB. However, when using the line tool, no button finishes the line editing. RMB only erases the line.

[image: Example of the line tool I'm trying to use here]

Answer (score 2):

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will finish the stroke